# Set container width according to image.network widh in flutter?

Tags: flutter, widget, flutter-container

i want to fix my container size(width) according to the image which is getting from api(image.network..).So, how can i go for this?

i am trying to set dynamic width of container according to image which i get from image.network() in flutter.

Comment: have you tried this? `fit: BoxFit.cover` this command is making your image fit into your container height/width, but if you tried to set container width according of image. you will get overflow error in your console when the image was bigger than your screen size.

Answer (score 0):

You will get overflow error in your device when the image was bigger than your device screen. I recommend you to use this

```
 Container(
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              image: NetworkImage(
                  'image link'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```